# Inconsistent initialization syntax

Tags: c#

In C#, the following is valid syntax, and this makes sense:

```
string[] v = {"a","b"};
```

But now consider this.  Suppose we define

```
void method(string[] p) {...};
```

Then the following is not valid:

```
method({"a","b"});
```

which is inconsistent with the above.

Are there technical reasons that preclude the method call here from being valid syntax?  That is, is there some ambiguity in interpretation of the syntax?  Or is there some issue with memory management or persistence that makes it impossible to implement?

Edit:
Eric Lippert's answer below is interesting - but it answers the "why" of design, which I wasn't actually asking (and indeed this question was originally closed because it appeared as though I was asking for his sort of answer).

L.B's answer may indeed not be the original "reason why" this syntax was no allowed (as per Eric L. comments).  However, L.B's answer, as of now, is certainly a correct technical reason why such syntax could not be allowed, which is actually the question I was asking, so I choose to select L.B's answer as correct (though honestly it was a hard choice...).

Comment: This is valid:  `method(new[] {"a","b"});`

Comment: Suppose you have another method `void method(KeyValuePair<string,string> p) {}` Which one is invoked? (See initialization of a dictionary)

Comment: It isn't inconsistent.  It is based on type inference.  However, there is a reasonable limit to how far C# takes type inference before strong typing begins to break down and L.B just gave a great example of where that can happen.

Comment: Yeah, type inference is only syntactic sugar provided for convenience only in unambiguous cases.

Comment: @L.B: These were the answers I was looking for.  L.B.'s answer is certainly sufficient to rule out allowing the syntax, (and it's not opinion-based, but technical and factual).  Thanks.  (So L.B., enter your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.)

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh -- He can't, the question has been closed.  Answers on closed questions are not allowed.

Comment: @rory.ap : Hmmm.  I guess I just fail to see how a simple question on a technical issue, that did indeed result in a technical answer, is a question asking for opinions.  And I guess perhaps I just thought the question might get opened again, so that it might have a clear answer for others to see.  In any event, I have my answer - thanks L.B

Comment: VB fanboy interruption : that would work in VB.NET, even `Dim v = {"a","b"}` will be inferred as string array

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh You are pushing hard :) OK I also vote it as `reopen`, Your question in this form is clearly not "opinion-based"

Comment: Though LB's answer is plausible, I note that the feature you are critiquing was from C# 1.0. Type inference was not added until C# 2.0, and initializers of key value pairs with object initializers was not added until C# 3.0.  So it is a logical error to reason about the design of the C# 1.0 feature based on characteristics of languages that were designed years later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have another method

```
void method(KeyValuePair<string,string> p) {}
```

calling it like `method({"a","b"});` would result in ambiguity..

Remember `{"a","b"}` may also be *KeyValuePair<>* as here

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "a", "b" } };
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The initialization syntax for `Dictionary<K,V>` corresponds to the parameters of its `Add()` method and works for any collection type. This is an error: `KeyValuePair<int,int> x = {0,0}; `

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: it's an oddity of the grammar. I've always considered this to be a "wart". There are a number of ways you can look at this thing and say it is weird.  It is weird that it is one of the few situations where:

```
T x = y;
```

and

```
T x; x = y;
```

are different.  Or, another way to look at it is that it is weird that a local variable initializer is a context in which something *that is not an expression* can appear.

Or another way to look at it is it is really weird that this is the only situation in which a new array is created but "new" does not appear anywhere.

Or another way to look at it is it is really weird that arrays can be initialized like this, but no other collection constructs can.  It makes arrays seem particularly special and important, even though they are often not the right tool for the job.

I think if we had to do it all over again, probably initializers would require `new[]` to their left.

> Are there technical reasons that preclude the method call here from being valid syntax? That is, is there some ambiguity in interpretation of the syntax?

Not really. Don't read too much into this oddity. My advice is to avoid the syntax entirely; stick with proper collection initializers or array initializers. They have almost exactly the same syntax, but are legal anywhere an expression is legal.

Regarding the other answer, of L.B.:  Though this answer does plausibly point out that there is a design issue here, it ignores the historical perspective. The feature being critiqued was created in C# 1.0, years before generic type inference (C# 2.0) or other braced collection initializers (C# 3.0) were added.  So one cannot make a justification for the design choices of a 1.0 feature on the basis of some conflict with features that came years later. The C# design team tries to be forward looking, but they were not *that* forward looking!

Comment: "... it is really weird that arrays can be initialized like this, but no other collection constructs can". Isn't somehow similar to this type of initialization: `new Office { Employees = { "Denise", "John" } };` where Employees is a list of strings that is created in the Office constructor? How is this type of initialization called?

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: That's a collection initializer. My point is that you can't say `List<int> myList = { 1, 2, 3, };`  but you can say `int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3};`, and so arrays are special.  Why should arrays be special but lists not be special?  Particularly since, as you correctly note, you *can* do that in the context of an object or collection initializer.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Its a shame that one can no longer ask the type of question to which your answer truly applies, because they are "opinion" questions.  The "opinions" of people with your experience are rather valuable, and its a shame that SO no longer recognizes this.

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh: I am well known around here for pushing back on vague "why" questions; that said, I think your question in its present form is clear. For more thoughts on this see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio/323382#323382  and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language/293819#293819

Comment: Interesting reading.  Makes me feel better about this question and its evolution...

Comment: Collection initializers depend on an `Add()` method to work. Arrays have to be populated by index (which the array initialization syntax effectively does).